# Which cases earn the most money?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In other words, Which cases have the highest opportunity for me to get an expensive skin or knife? Is it the operation cases? Weapon cases or the Tournament Cases?

Comment: On average, all cases give a loss.

Comment: @Bob Yes Ive opened about 30 and all I get is Blue skins. The only good stuff is from tradeups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In almost every case you will have the same amount of money from all the items, pretty much nothing. It really depends on what the worth is on the market (ex. Huntsman is worth $100 so you open a huntsman case). Each case has different items and their worth on the market dictates if it is worth it to open the case or not.